# I lost my uncle few Weeks ago due to the covid 19 and I have his wallet

Tags: private-key

I have my uncle wallet and I don’t have his private key can anyone help

Comment: I meant any amount requested I’m ready to Pay

Comment: What is the wallet software / is it a paper wallet?

Comment: To assist you further, would you let us know what type of wallet is it?

Comment: Hello, welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange! I'm sorry to hear of your loss, in order to help you'll need to provide more information though. More info about the software used / what you have access to is needed. **Note**: DO NOT share wallet login info, private keys, or mnemonic seed phrases with anyone online, anyone who has that info can steal the coins. Also, offers of reward are not allowed here; if you provide enough info someone will likely help out anyways.

Comment: Okay the wallet is blockchain.

Comment: And how do we chat privately on this site? Do y’all use icq?

Comment: @jeff there is no private chat on this site. Anyone capable of helping should be able to do so publicly; there is no need for you to disclose sensitive info. Are you capable of logging into your uncles blockchain wallet? Do you have possession of a backup of that wallet?

Comment: Can you be very precise about what you have and what wallet he was using?

Comment: As the user has not followed up with more information in over a month, I've voted to close this question as "lacking details". To reopen the question, please edit your post  to provide more information. Please do not provide any sensitive information.

Answer (score 4):

> I have my uncle wallet

The only important thing in a wallet is the private key(s). Usually the wallet's contents are protected by a password. Without the password, no one can get the private key out from the wallet.

The actual money is better thought of as being in the public blockchain. Money is not really inside the wallet.

> and I don’t have his private key

Then you don't have any control over his money.

You must find the private-key or a seed-phrase (recovery phrase) - usually consisting of 12 or 24 words from a special list. The private-key can be recreated from the recovery phrase. Prudent people put this information somewhere safe. Some people stamp the recovery phrase onto a fire-resistant  metal sheet and lock that away somewhere.

> can anyone help

You will get lots of offers from dishonest people trying to steal the money or, to trick you out of money in "unlocking fees" or other fictions. Don't trust new people who communicate in private. Never give anyone else anything that looks like a private-key or recovery-phrase.

But no, you really need to find the key or recovery phrase. Nothing else.